# How to map touch coordinates after setPolyToPoly in Android?

Tags: android, view, touch, coordinates

First of all some transformation for view is applied using Matrix:

```
    // Resetting matrix from previous transformations.
    mMatrix.reset();

    // View's rectangle angles' transformations.
    mMatrix.setPolyToPoly(new float[] {
            0,          0,
            getWidth(), 0,
            0,          getHeight(),
            getWidth(), getHeight()
    }, 0, newCoords, 0, 4);

    // Asking view to invalidate itself.
    invalidate();
```

Then in onDraw method applying transformation encoded in Matrix:

```
    // Applying transformation.
    canvas.concat(mMatrix);

    // Invalidating.
    super.onDraw(canvas);
```

And finally trying to map touch coordinates to fit them for new transformation in dispatchTouchEvent:

```
    // We need an array of float coordinates to map them with our matrix.
    float[] coordinates = new float[] {
            event.getX(), event.getY()
    };

    // Mapping touch points.
    mMatrix.mapPoints(coordinates);

    // Applying shifts for current touch.
    event.setLocation(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
```

Using this code we're always getting wrong shifts for touch coordinates. The best effect I could achieve was with this line:

```
event.offsetLocation(event.getX() - coordinates[0], event.getY() - coordinates[1]);
```

instead of this one:

```
event.setLocation(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
```

But it's still incorrect. Moreover, this code works in a completely wrong way when we are applying setRotation for view (what makes me wonder, because in this case coordinates system should be also rotated).

Do you have any suggestions about right ways in Android API how to sync touch coordinates with view's setPolyToPoly transformation?

Comment: call `mapPoints` on `invert()`ed `Matrix`

Comment: @pskink , thank you, now everything works as it should even with rotation applied!

Comment: da,  haraszo... ;-)